# Sending verification mail with out acessToken

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I have a trouble.

I'm using Auth0.
When I create a user, I want to send verification mail at last(reason Rollback DB).

And I found this URL(API?).

```
/api/v2/jobs/verification-email
```

I saw the doc, and it looks like to need accessToken(by Auth0) in HTTPHeader.
In this case, user not verified yet. So not creating acessToken too.

Am I using wrong API?

Comment: Please share the code u have used for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To access such services where user authorization is not expected, or available, you should still request for a access token to validate the identity of your client (caller).

You can do it by configuring your client and requesting the accessToken as *client_credentials* grant type.

You can request for a client access token and send in header of your API call request

Read more on https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/client-credentials

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for All!! I got It.

```
public void sendVerificationEmail(String userId) throws Auth0Exception {

    AuthAPI authAPI = new AuthAPI(domain, clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthRequest authRequest = authAPI.requestToken(AUTH0_URL);
    TokenHolder holder = authRequest.execute();
    ManagementAPI mgmt = new ManagementAPI(domain, holder.getAccessToken());

    Request<Job> request = mgmt.jobs().sendVerificationEmail(userId, null);

    request.execute();
}
```